# How to use Tf-idf features for training your model?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification, naivebayes, tfidfvectorizer

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf= True, 
                       min_df = 5, 
                       norm= 'l2', 
                       ngram_range= (1,2), 
                       stop_words ='english')

feature1 = tfidf.fit_transform(df.Rejoined_Stem)
array_of_feature = feature1.toarray()
```

I used the above code to get features for my text document.

```
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB # Multinomial Naive Bayes on Lemmatized Text
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df['Rejoined_Lemmatize'], df['Product'], random_state = 0)
X_train_counts = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
clf = MultinomialNB().fit(X_train_counts, y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(tfidf.transform(X_test))
```

Then I used this code to train my model. 
Can someone explain how exactly are the above features being used while training the model as that feature1 variable is not being used anywhere while training ??

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you did not use `feature1` as you performed another transformation `X_train_count`.

Let’s go through your code in a logical flow and use only the variables that where used in the feature extraction and model training.

```py
# imports used
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

# split data random state 0 and test_size 0.25 default as you did not give the test_size

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['Rejoined_Lemmatize']], df['Product'], random_state = 0)

# you initiated your transformer to `fit_transform` X_train, and `transform` X_test

tfidf = TfidfVectorizer(sublinear_tf= True, 
                       min_df = 5, 
                       norm= 'l2', 
                       ngram_range= (1,2), 
                       stop_words ='english')


X_train_counts = tfidf.fit_transform(X_train)
X_test_counts = tfidf.transform(X_test)

# you initiated your model and fit X_train_counts and y_train
clf = MultinomialNB()
cls.fit(X_train_counts, y_train)

# you predicted from your transformed features
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test_counts)
```

There is a better way to use Scikit-learn API which eliminates confusion and will help you not get mixed up. That way uses `Pipelines`

```py
# imports used: see Pipeline
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

# split data random state 0 and test_size 0.25 default as you did not give the test_size

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['Rejoined_Lemmatize']], df['Product'], random_state = 0)

# get the params
tfidf_params = dict(sublinear_tf= True, 
                       min_df = 5, 
                       norm= 'l2', 
                       ngram_range= (1,2), 
                       stop_words ='english')

# create a Pipeline that will do features transformation then pass to the model

clf = Pipeline(steps=[
('features', TfidfVectorizer(**tfidf_params)),
('model', MultinomialNB())
])

# Use clf as a model, fit X_train and y_train
cls.fit(X_train, y_train)

# predicted 
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
```

What pipeline does, in `.fit` is doing the fit_transform on the data, and then pass it to the model. In `.predict`, it will do the transform before passing to the model.

The best the thing about this approach is that you can easily switch models or transformer with ease. Here is an example on baseline comparison of models:

```py
# collection to store results 
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd

from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer

# models to test
from sklearn.linear_model import PassiveAggressiveClassifier 
from sklearn.linear_model import RidgeClassifierCV
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegressionCV     


# insistent our storage 
bench_mark = defaultdict(list)

# split data random state 0 and test_size 0.25 default as you did not give the test_size

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df[['Rejoined_Lemmatize']], df['Product'], random_state = 0)

# get the transformer params
tfidf_params = dict(sublinear_tf= True, 
                       min_df = 5, 
                       norm= 'l2', 
                       ngram_range= (1,2), 
                       stop_words ='english')

# list of models we would like to complete 
models = [
PassiveAggressiveClassifier(C=1e-1,max_iter=1e3,  tol=1e3), 
RidgeClassifierCV(scoring='roc_auc', cv=10),
LogisticRegressionCV(cv=5,solver='saga',scoring='accuracy', random_state=1, n_jobs=-1),
SGDClassifier(loss='log', random_state=1, max_iter=101),
 ]

# train, test and store each model 
for model in models:

    # our pipeline is changed to accept model
    clf = Pipeline(steps=[
        ('features', TfidfVectorizer(**tfidf_params)),
        ('model', model) #just model not model() as we have done that in models list
    ])

    clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
     score = clf.score(X_test,y_test)

    model_name = clf.named_steps['model'].__class__.__name__ # hack to get name

    model_params = clf.named_steps['model']. get_params()


    print(f'{model_name} Scored: {score:.3f}\n')

    bench_mark['model_name'].append(model_name)
    bench_mark['score'].append(score)
    bench_mark['model'].append(clf)
    bench_mark['used_params'].append(model_params)

# in the end, place the bench_mark to DataFrame
models_df = pd.DataFrame(bench_mark)

# now you have the trained modes in DataFrame, their scores and parameters. 
#You can access and use any model.

logistic_reg = models_df[models_df['model_name']=='LogisticRegressionCV']['model'].iloc[0]

y_preds = logistic_reg.predict(X_test)
```

Hopes this helps

Comment: Thank you so much. Also, can I use pipelines to pass multiple models and test their accuracy?@Prayson W. Daniel

Comment: Yes, you can easily pass different models and compare then. I will edit my answer to include that